# How can I render new random context in react after time interval?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying render random content from array, later from database. It work, but is a better way to do it?
**Here is code-example**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Fade from "react-reveal/Fade";

const quotes = [
  "„111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 “",
  "„22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222",
  "„3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333“",
];

const Quotes = () => {
  const [quote, setSeconds] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const q = quotes;
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setSeconds(() => q[Math.floor(Math.random() * q.length)]);
    }, 5000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Fade right>
      <p>{quote}</p>
    </Fade>
  );
};

export default Quotes;
```

Comment: What do you mean "better"? More performant? More react-like? Without being specific, you're likely to get subjective unhelpful answers.

Comment: Hi, @Nathan. I mean better standart of code, It was my first post so thanks for your comment and later I'll be more specific :)

Answer (score 0):

IDK if this is better or not,
But you can rearrange or shuffle your array initially & then loop over the same.
Once you reach the last element, then again shuffle the array.

For shuffling, you can use

```
const shuffleThis = arr => arr.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5));
```

Further, If you use MongoDB, then it has an aggregate **$sample**, which can be used.